# Showing an element of a permutation raised to a specific power is equal to the permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Here's my permutation:

$\sigma = \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
7 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 12 & 11 & 13 & 1 & 8 & 10 & 9 \\
\end{array} \right)$

I'm trying to find $\tau$ in $S_{13}$ such that $\tau^3$ = $\sigma$, or show that such an element doesn't exist. I've started by writing $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint cycles, and got (1, 7, 12, 10)(2, 4, 5, 6, 3)(8, 11)(9, 13)
,and I've established that $ord (\sigma)$ = 20 as 20 = $lcm (2, 4, 5)$
I was thinking about using Lagrange, but was not sure if that works for permutations.

Thank you!

Comment: So, start with $x=(1\ 7\ 12\ 10)$. Can you find a permutation $y$ such that $y^3=x$?

Comment: Is there a way to go about finding such an $y$, or is it really trial and error? Is it also the case that my $y$ would consist of the same elements as my $x$, but then in a different order?

Comment: Don't ask; just try; then, analyze.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since the order of $\sigma$ is $20$, we know $\sigma^{21} = \sigma$.

Thus $\tau = \sigma^7$ is a solution.

An approach of this kind will work whenever a group element has an order coprime to the "root" you want to extract.